# count hashtags in pig latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have sample dataset which looks something like this:

```
tmj_dc_mgmt, Washington, en, 483, 457, 256, ['hiring', 'BusinessMgmt', 'Washington', 'Job']
SRiku0728, 福山市, ja, 6705, 357, 273, ['None']
BesiktaSeyma_, Akyurt, tr, 12921, 1801, 283, ['None']
AnnaKFrick, Virginia, en, 5731, 682, 1120, ['Investment', 'PPP', 'Bogota', 'jobs']
Accprimary, Manchester, en, 1650, 268, 404, ['None']
```

The data inside square bracket's are hashtags, I want to count top 10 hashtags in whole list.

I have reached this far, not sure how to move further.

```
twitter_feed = LOAD '/twitter-data-mining/15' USING PigStorage(','); 

hash_tags = FOREACH twitter_feed GENERATE $7;

fallten = FILTER hash_tags BY $1 MATCHES '\w+'|'\w+(\s\w+)*' 

DUMP fallten;
```

Any help in correct direction would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: What does fallten contain? Also laoding data using ',' will not give you the correct results.

Comment: fallten doesn't give me correct result, I was wonder if I could extract only hash tags inside single quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The load statement is incorrect.There are two ways you can achieve this to get the hashtags.First way is to load using '[' and then manipulating the string to counts the hashtags.Second way is to load the entire line and use regex_extract_all for getting the hashtags. I am listing the first way.See below

1. Load using '[' as the delimiter which will give 2 fields.
2. Extract the second field i.e. $1 and replace right bracket ']' and
       all quotes '''.
3. Tokenize the resulting fields to get all the hashtags.
4. Filter the hashtags that does not match 'None'
5. Group the hashtags
6. Count the groupings

Note: I am not changing the case of the hashtags,since it is trivial

```
A = LOAD 'test10.txt' USING PigStorage('[');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(REPLACE($1,']',''),'\'','');
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(*));
D = FILTER C BY NOT($0 MATCHES 'None');
E = GROUP D by $0;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE group,COUNT(D.$0);
DUMP F;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]